# How to apply an extension to only some specializations of a generic type?

Tags: arrays, generics, swift

Is there a way to apply an extension to a generic type so that it conforms to a protocol, when that extension will be valid only for certain specializations of the generic type?

For instance, consider this protocol which returns a dictionary counting the frequency of values contained by an instance conforming to the protocol:

```
// a type conforming to this protocol should return a dictionary
// which counts the frequencies of values contained by the type instance
protocol ConvertibleToFrequencyDictionary {
   typealias ItemType
   func dictionaryCountingFrequencies<ItemType:Hashable>() -> Dictionary<ItemType,Int>
}
```

Because the values being counted must serve as keys to the dictionary, the values must be of a type which conforms to Hashable. This is expressed by the type constraint on the definition of the generic `dictionaryCountingFrequencies` method. (I don't see any way to define the type constraint directly on the associated type, e.g., in the "typealias" declaration.)

Now consider this extension on Array, intended to make it conform to the protocol:

```
extension Array : ConvertibleToFrequencyDictionary {
  typealias ItemType=Element
  func dictionaryCountingFrequencies<ItemType:Hashable>() -> Dictionary<ItemType,Int> {
    var valueToCount = Dictionary<ItemType,Int>()
    for item in self {
      if let existingCount = valueToCount[item] {
        valueToCount.updateValue(value: existingCount + 1, forKey: item)
      } else {
        valueToCount.updateValue(value: 1, forKey: item)
      }
    }
    return valueToCount;
  }
}
```

This should return the frequencies of every distinct value appearing in Array. But of course, since these values must be hashable, this extension should only work when it is applied to an `Array<T:Hashable>`.

Yet this doesn't work for `Array<Int>`, even though Int is Hashable.

Why not? If you write an extension on a generic type, must that extension be able to work for every possible specialization of the generic type?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `SequenceType` instead of `Array`, this gives you more types this applies too and then you limit the type of the `Element` with `where`.

- `Array` extensions need `where Element : SomeProtocol`
- `SequenceType` extensions need `where Generator.Element : SomeProtocol`

The problem you were having was not that `Int` was not `Hashable`, it was that Item was not necessarily `Hashable`. A cast to `ItemType` also worked since it was always `Hashable` in this example.

Personally I would not use a generic for this. Since Element already covers everything you can store in an Array there is no need to make it type-fuzzy.

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Hashable {

    func dictionaryCountingFrequencies() -> Dictionary<Generator.Element,Int> {
        var valueToCount = Dictionary<Generator.Element,Int>()
        for item in self {

            if let existingCount = valueToCount[item] {
                valueToCount.updateValue(existingCount + 1, forKey: item)
            } else {
                valueToCount.updateValue(1, forKey: item)
            }
        }
        return valueToCount;
    }
}

let array = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1,2,3,3]

let freqDict = array.dictionaryCountingFrequencies()
// prints [5: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 1: 4, 4: 1]
freqDict[5]
// prints 1
```